# Near-cli with ledger: Ledger not needed for signing

Tags: nearprotocol

On NEAR testnet

Whenever I do `near login` with **near-cli** and use ledger a new `FullAccess` key is generated with the PK stored within `~/.near-credentials` locally.

No problem here so far but then this: In that sense I do not need the ledger to e.g. send funds from this account to some other account as the locally stored PK signs the tx. So, I do not understand why I would then use the ledger in the first place?

The FullAccess key does not seem to become invalid. It is still listed after the session when I do `near keys` `<account_name>`.testnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:
In order to take full advantage to use the ledger you will need to add the flag `--useLedgerKey`. Moreover, `near login` should be avoided with ledger as it otherwise will store a FullAccess key locally.